# Internal discrete fibrations

Tags: category-theory

The [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+fibration) for discrete fibrations says that an internal functor is an internal discrete fibration iff the square given there is 'Cartesian' -- does this mean that it is cartesian as a morphism in the arrow category, or simply that it is a pullback?

Comment: Intuitively a pullback seems to match the external notion of a discrete fibration, but this seems an odd choice of language in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same thing. If a category $\mathcal{E}$ has pullbacks, then a square in $\mathcal{E}$ is cartesian as a morphism in $\mathcal{E}^{\to}$ (with respect to  $\mathsf{cod} : \mathcal{E}^{\to} \to \mathcal{E}$) if and only if it is a pullback square in $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Ah, very cool.  Thank you.